# Is Abstracting your code too much a bad use of SOLID Principles?

Tags: class-design, solid, single-responsibility, abstraction, factory

After an unresolved argument with a friend I decided to ask the stack overflow community. Is there something like abstracting your code too much? Which of the following is the better option. We come from different coding languages so I am explaining this the same way I would to him. Assume everything below as summaries to what your respective languages would do.

IMPORTANT CONDITIONS THAT WILL ALWAYS BE EXIST:

- There is only 1 table and 1 db
- There will only be a GET_ALL. No partial or specific collections.
- FACTORY CLASS and HELPER CLASS will always be called together NO MATTER WHAT.

```
FACTORY CLASS {

  //This method will check cache and create a repository instance of the table if one does not exist
  createNewRepository();

  //This will collect the records from the instantiated repository  
  getAllFromRepository();

  //This will return the data that was collected   
  returnData; 
}
```

or

```
FACTORY CLASS {

  //This method will check cache and create a repository instance of the table if one does not exist   
  createNewRepository(); 
}

HELPER CLASS {

  //This will collect the records from the instantiated repository  
  getAllFromRepository();

  //This will return the data that was collected   
  returnData; 
}
```

We both have different views on the SOLID principles apparently.

I believe a class should have single responsibility in the sense of "This factory class' responsibility is to get me the data from the db" that will include the functionality required to achieve this.

He believes a class should have single responsibility in the sense of "This factory class' responsibility is to spin up the repository and not to call the data. A helper class will call the data"

I agree with him if it was the case that there was different variations of how the data is called but because the data will always be checked>createdIfNull>collected and this entire process is the functionality of "accessing the data to use" shouldn't it be in a single class?

Comment: I'd say, on the contrary, keep abstracting code until you can't anymore. You should read 'clean code' by robert martin, it gives plenty of reasons as to why.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: We shouldn't just abstract for abstraction's sake. You can't sustainably assume that every project ever created _will_ change in every conceivable way. There needs to be a justifiable argument in favor of abstraction, other than "just do it" (e.g. expected future changes, or the stakeholder's explicit desire to prioritize faster future development over faster current development). I'm not going to build a bigger garage today on the off chance that I will have a limo in the future. The cost of doing so does not outweight the odds of it happening.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Abstraction is a tool, not a methodology.  Use it to obtain a result, not to do it for the sake of abstraction.  That's a bit like purposefully adding newlines in code for "readability" sake.  If it doesn't make sense to do so, it is self-defeating.

Comment: Who said do it 'for the sake of it'? There are plenty of reasons as to why compliance with the SRP pays dividends. I haven't listed them myself, which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer. Do you disagree with the SRP?

Comment: Can you guys make these questions? Very good points are made and voting on them will be better to discuss over

Comment: @BrendonGrundlingh - they're questions I believe have been answered already, in many forms. The book itself, as well as many others,  addresses abstraction and design in detail - if somebody wants to disagree with the principles of OOP I'm going to have to get on with something else I'm afraid.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ god dam it! i was counting on your vote!!

Comment: @Ewan - I actually agree with you though!? I gave you a vote, I think a clear separation of concerns as you suggest is absolutely the right idea.

Comment: @JayMee - Its not specifically disagreeing with OOP, its the interpretation of it that is somewhat confusing specifically with the question I posted. Abstract to a point of singular responsibility or to the point of singular functionality. Do you brush your teeth on your own or get people to open the tap, give you the toothbrush and then you yourself brush your teeth. Won't this specific example be abstracting too much?

Comment: @BrendonGrundlingh - you're one of the very few people in this thread asking interesting questions. Single responsibility vs. single functionality is an interesting one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would side with your enemy on this one.

- The 'create a database and table logic' is clearly technically a separate responsibility from the 'get data from database' logic.
- You can imagine the creation code getting pretty complex if we consider database migrations etc. Enough lines of code to justify a separate file.
- You might want to restrict calling code to either creating or retrieving

In general, the time cost of making something more generic like this is hard to judge. One person might find it onerous and long winded another might do it as standard and think it quicker.

In my view YAGNI is never a good argument. If it's correct and done or quick to do, then its academic whether someone thinks they might not need it.

Comment: Disagree with this answer. Abstracting prematurely leads to higher cognitive load in comprehending code and most often lead to abstractions that turn out to be unnecessary or - more importantly - wrong and difficult to reverse. I believe that abstracting hard dependencies at boundaries of systems is a sensible starting point and all other abstraction should be driven by need. Of course different people have a different idea of what "abstraction" actually means.

Comment: @AntP you should write an answer so we can see by the voting which view various peoples experience has lead them to agree with

Comment: I agree with @Ewan, make it a question so we can vote. Very good points are made in this post

Comment: `In my view YAGNI is never a good argument.` Does your house have a garage that is able to house a limo, or a helicopter, or both? Apparently, you can't argue that you're not going to need this, as per your own statement. This is clearly incorrect. YAGNI is _always_ a relevant argument, the only debatable topic is where you draw the line of relevance. The odds of a change occurring need to outweigh the cost of implementing the abstraction that simplifies the change.

Comment: The notion of 'premature abstraction' directly implies that there is a cost to abstraction. It's an approach to design, with a cost I'm not aware of. What is the cost to complying with the idea of a separation of concerns? These are OOP fundamentals. This answer is absolutely correct, keep it nice and clear, nice and separate.

Comment: @Flater "If it's correct and done or quick to do" If I had the super garage it would be worth more money, even if I don't have a helicopter

Comment: @Ewan: Feedback to your answer should not be posted as a separate answer. Ant isn't answering OP's question, they're responding to your overgeneralized assertion that infinite abstraction for abstraction's sake is always the best solution.

Comment: @Flater - this argument of 'for the sake of it' is facile. There are valid reasons for abstraction to the Nth degree. Why do you keep saying for the sake of it?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: As per your own statement: `I'd say, on the contrary, keep abstracting code until you can't anymore`. So why are you drawing the line at N abstraction levels, and why not at N+1? Or N+2? ... This is the issue: every next level of abstraction needs to justify its existence. It's not a default "yes".

Comment: @Flater - I think you've missed the point again. I don't believe the line should be drawn. But that doesn't mean I'm suggesting it for the sake of it. Again - these are OOP fundamentals, the concept of single responsibility is not new, nor is it up for debate usually.

Comment: `This is the issue: every next level of abstraction needs to justify its existence. It's not a default "yes".` - that directly contradicts the single responsibility principle. If you're presented with a unit that *could* be extracted, given the fact a decision needs to be made, it's probably doing too much or, at least, is not doing one single thing.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Your response is a non-sequitur. At no point did I argue against SRP. I argued against the assertion that abstraction is always good regardless of context. And you're contradicting yourself: (A) `I don't believe the line should be drawn.` (B) `There are valid reasons for abstraction to the Nth degree` If (A) is correct, then (B) doesn't need "to the Nth degree" since there's allegedly no upper limit.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ if you don't draw a line at where to stop abstracting you are by definition abstracting for the sake of abstracting, as there's never going to be an end to it.

Comment: @jwenting - absolutely not. If there are reasons behind what I'm suggesting, reasons very very well established, how is that at all for the sake of it?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: `that directly contradicts the single responsibility principle. If you're presented with a unit that could be extracted` The SRP _**is**_ that justification to abstract that I'm taking about. You're still not getting that "always abstract" and "SRP is a valid reason to abstract" are two completely different things. You intended the latter, but you stated the former.

Comment: `keep abstracting code until you can't anymore` - "can't" meaning it now does one single thing. Can't believe I'm having to spell out the principles of OOP.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ the only reason you've given is that you need to abstract because you need to abstract because it's written somewhere you need to abstract, and that you need to never stop abstracting. So abstraction becomes its own justification according to your logic.

Comment: @jwenting - `it's written somewhere you need to abstract` - yes, with good reason. And an in-depth explanation of those good reasons. Please read the book, or one of the many other hundreds of books discussing SRP.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I've seen way too many very bad examples of your logic taken to its logical end point. Which led to one program having a class to add 2 integers, with a method add(int), which was used in lue of doing like int i=a+b; THAT's the end result of your idea

Comment: @jwenting - that sounds neat and tidy to me. I don't see the problem. It's testable, clear, almost self-documenting. What is the issue?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ `Can't believe I'm having to spell out the principles of OOP` Then don't post answers in questions asking about the principles of OOP.

Comment: @Flater - I didn't, I haven't posted a single answer. This is precisely why it was a comment.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: You make spurious assertions, do not back them up, and either respond in non-sequiturs or dodge the topic whenever someone points out the flaw in your statement. This is pointless.

Comment: @Flater - it's not my assertion to back-up, it's a tried and tested principle. I have pointed the OP to a very very well-respected resource in which it discusses, in length, the benefits.

Comment: @jwenting - I think you need to relax a bit. How is it any more horribly performing? How is it unreadable? You know *exactly* what that method is going to do.

Comment: @Ewan: I know it's an analogy, but that super garage, you have to pay additional utilities, property tax, etc to maintain it. If you never put a helicopter in, it might not be worth to have paid for the upkeep. The same is true in software, but additional cost to write it and more cognitive difficulty. Rarely is anything totally free.

Comment: @whatsisname I do cover that in the answer. usually you only hear YAGNI _after_ its already been coded. and in this case we are talking about maybe 5 more lines of code

Comment: Can I also just ask this (again) - we're talking about 'costs' here, what costs?!?! What is the cost to a nice separation of concerns from the start?? The argument about whether this is 'worth it' or not is predicated on the assumption of a cost to ensuring SRP. There is no cost. It's maintainable, easier to write, most certainly easier to read, it's self-documenting, it's more testable. I'm totally lost as to why the approach suggested in this answer is even up for debate. It is a very short-sighted view that would suggest the time taken to abstract > time taken dealing with monoliths.

Comment: Further still, you're not actively abstracting, or at least - you shouldn't be. From the start you should write 'stuff' that has one job. That's all. Surprised this topic has so much heat after years and years of OOP being tried and tested.

Comment: @jaymee 100% agree YAGNI isnt about costs its about need. no one is suggesting you spend time building unrequested features.

Answer (score 2):

> "This factory class' responsibility is to get me the data from the db"

That's like saying "I'm going to use this car manufacturer to drive to work". You're not. You're going to use a car *that was built by this manufacturer* to drive to work.

The car's responsibility is to let you drive around. The car manufacturer's responsibility is to build cars.

I understand where you're coming from. We all make similar "shortcut mistakes" at one time. But your assumption relies on the notion that *a repository is only ever used for collecting all data*.

While that may be the case **today**, it might not be the case **tomorrow**.

SOLID predominantly focuses on the future. Implementing SOLID doesn't make your (already working, non-SOLID) code work better. Implementing SOLID ensures that it will be easier to implement **future changes**.

> IMPORTANT CONDITIONS THAT WILL ALWAYS BE EXIST:

When I take your assertion at heart, that nothing will ever change, then implement SOLID is irrelevant.

However, whenever statements like these are made, the speaker is usually not in a position to guarantee that things will never change. They're looking at it from today's point of view, not tomorrow's.
You can't always know what's coming in the future. Maybe you start using a different data provider, maybe you now need to merge data from two data providers, ...

---

That being said, I'm not quite sure what the purpose of the helper is.

- Why is this helper's method not part of the repository itself?
- What's the meaningful difference between calling the repository method directly, and calling the helper method which calls the repository method?

That may be a detail that you intentionally omitted from your question for the sake of clarity. In either case, my answer stands: retrieving the data and instantiating the class that retrieves data are two completely separate things.

Masons are not brick walls. Car mechanics are not cars. Wheat farmers are not wheat. Repository factories are not repositories.

Comment: I keep looking for a short 'bumper sticker slogan' way to describe SOLID to non-engineers. "You can't always know what's coming in the future." feels as close as anything.

Comment: @MarcelWilson I think "solid" is a bad adjective to describe it, I would've used "nimble", i.e. agility and flexibility. "Float like a butterfly" and all that.

Comment: I just meant I was trying to describe SOLID principles to non-engineers without having to spend 45 minutes going over each letter in the acronym.  I agree that nimble and agile are perfectly fine but they already 'know' those words.  I kept looking for a succinct way to describe the whole concept.  Something execs can chew on and feel they understand in a way that felt 'good enough' for me.  Your line about the future felt like it really hit the mark.  I plan on using it soon to re-emphasise the concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Factory, that means you found the need to decouple the implementation of an object from its contract. Factories are good at that. In this case, the dependency is on what gets the data.

If the Factory is now responsible for getting the data too, what was the point all along? Now the dependency is on the Factory. It stops looking so much like a factory. It has a static repository, and now static methods for accessing that static repository. Any class using this factory is now coupled to the way the factory gets the data.

The goal should be to have the cached Repository be the only static element in this whole system. That way how the Repository itself acts is irrelevant to whoever asks for it.

---

You can do this by acting on the Factory's created Repository:

```
// Creates and/or gets a cache of the repository
Repository repository = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository();

// Get all the data from the repository
data = repository.GetAllData();
```

---

You can do this by Implementing the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
class Repository 
{
    public static readonly Instance = new Repository();

    private Repository() {
        // Connect to the repository here.
    }
}
```

And then acting on it:

```
Repository repository = Repository.Instance;
data = repository.GetAllData();
```

---

You can do this using a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
class Repository {
    private Repository() {
       // Connect to repository here
    }

    public static Repository GetRepository() {
        if (cached) {
            return CachedRepository;
        }
        else {
            return new Repository();
        }
    }
}
```

And then acting on it:

```
Repository repository = Repository.GetRepository();
data = repository.GetAllData();
```

---

In all cases we can inject the dependency however we want to the class that requires it.

`NeedsTheData d = new NeedsTheData(Repository.Instance);`

`NeedsTheData d = new NeedsTheData(Repository.GetRepository());`

And in the Factory's case, the factory should be the one taking care of decoupling, so we don't need to inject the Repository class.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the original code example leaves a lot to the imagination:

**FIRST EXAMPLE:**

```
public class Repsitory<TModel>
{
    public TModel GetAll(Func<TModel, bool> where)
    {
        //Will retrieve the data based on the where clause from the db
    }
}

public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public TModel GetAll<TModel>(Func<TModel, bool> where)
    {
        return GetRepository<TModel>().GetAll(where);
    }

    private Repsitory<TModel> GetRepository<TModel>()
    {
        //Checks if the cache contains an instance of the Repository<TModel> and returns it

        //IF no instance exists will create a new instance and cache it

        //Returns the new instance
    }
}
```

**SECOND EXAMPLE:**

```
public class Repsitory<TModel>
{
    public TModel GetAll(Func<TModel, bool> where)
    {
        //Will retrieve the data based on the where clause
    }
}

public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public Repsitory<TModel> GetRepository<TModel>()
    {
        //Checks if the cache contains an instance of the Repository<TModel> and returns it

        //IF no instance exists will create a new instance and cache it

        //Returns the new instance
    }
}

public class RepositoryHelper
{
    public TModel GetAll<TModel>(Func<TModel, bool> where)
    {
        return RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<TModel>().GetAll(where);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Flater here is a different example of the code for a clearer example of what is happening

Comment: wait, so you already have two classes and the argument is whether to add a third?

Comment: whats wrong with RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<Model>().GetAll() ?

Comment: @Ewan See this was the original question that caused this issue; whether or not to move the GetAll method out of the RepositoryFactory or not. SRP would say "yeah man go ahead"  because the Factories job is just to create repositories, not execute methods on them.

Comment: sure, but it doesnt say 'make a helper class that does nothing'

Comment: delete the helper class and the second is correct. or maybe make it a repository of repositories by adding the cache and a dictionary and moving the if exists code out of factory

Comment: @Ewan But the Helper class is not doing nothing. Its Executing the GetRepository function then executing the GetAll function. The name RepositoryHelper is probably not correct, but splitting it up into three classes makes logical sense. Or what is your 2 cents on this?